# Dart - conditional export based on another package?

Tags: dart

When creating a Dart package, you can [conditionally export files](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/create-packages#conditionally-importing-and-exporting-library-files) based on the use of certain dart core libraries in the host application. The conditions provided in the example are based around libraries such as `dart:io` or `dart:html`.

Is it possible to conditionally export based on the existence of other external packages? If so, what is the syntax? Something like `if (dart.package.<pkg_name>)`?

Comment: To be clear I have never really tried this but based on my current knowledge, No you cannot do this...

Comment: I don't think so either but figured since it is possible with internal libs, I would ask...

Answer (score 3):

No.

The feature technically (as specified) allows any "compilation environment" declaration to be checked, so you could do:

```dart
export "default.dart"
  if (i.want.more == "please") "more.dart";
```

and compile it with `-Di.want.more=please` on the command line.

In practice, compilers are allowed to limit the environment variables they support, and the current compilers do so to only those entries starting with `dart.library.`. And the parts of the compilation environment starting with `dart.` is reserved for the compilers themselves.

Answer (score 2):

The mechanism has vestigial support for arbitrary library identifiers, but in practice has become only eligible for dart:io and dart:html.  Users cannot add to this list.